# StartApp Rewarded Video ads not showing

Tags: java, android, rewardedvideoad, startapp

I'm implementing a android application which uses [StartApp](https://lp.startapp.com/uni_cube_btns_J17.html?channelCampId=204955356613&source=adwords&keyword=startapp&placement=&cmp=GGL-Search-Uni-ROW-EN-Brand&adg=Uni-Brand-Direct-Exact&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIuav9m9Ga3QIVyxSPCh3huAAXEAAYASAAEgJWVvD_BwE) ad network. In my app i use rewarded ads. I follow the instruction to the letter as the documentation suggested.

But when i load an Rewarded ad video it gives

ERROR EXECUTE EXCEPTION ERROR
SendGetWithResponseCode =[204]

Why i'm getting this error. I tried with both debug mode and release mode, emulator and real devices. Nothing is working.

Can anyone help?

```
startAppAd.loadAd(VIDEO, new AdEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
            Log.i("startApp","rewarded Loaded");
            startAppAd.showAd();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ad.getErrorMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    startAppAd.setVideoListener(new VideoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVideoCompleted() {
            Log.i("VideoWatched","watched");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Failed to load rewarded video :

Sometimes this message appears when there are no videos to show
Try using **VPN**

and  Check that FullScreenActivity is declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

See https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/Android-InApp-Documentation#activities

android API level above 16?

Comment: I am from sri Lanka. startAppAd platform don't serve ads for sri lanka. When i used VPN and use another country video ads loads.

Comment: @OmegaKi113r so congratulations.
the problem has been resolved

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the first line with this`startAppAd.loadAd(StartAppAd.AdMode.REWARDED_VIDEO, new AdEventListener() {`

Comment: Thank you, the reward not showing till changing the 'AdMode' form VIDEO to REWARDED_VIDEO